# How to find duplicates in one column in pandas in python

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe as follows where I want to keep the first occurrence of the duplicate and remove the remaining duplicates.

For example, consider the below mentioned dataframe. We can see duplicates in `title` column such as `nn nn`, `mm mm` etc. I want to remove them by keeping only the first occurrence of it.

```
id title
12 nn nn
11 nn nn
10 nn nn
18 mm mm
19 nn nn
06 mm mm
08 ll ll
09 jj jj
26 ll ll
```

My output should look as follows:

```
id title
12 nn nn
18 mm mm
08 ll ll
09 jj jj
```

I tried the following pandas code:

```
L= input_data[["id","title"]]
L_new = L[~L.duplicated()]
```

However, it does not remove duplicates as I wanted.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `input_data.groupby('title').first()`.

Answer (score 1):

We can using `head`

```
df.groupby('title').head(1)
   id  title
0  12  nn nn
3  18  mm mm
6   8  ll ll
7   9  jj jj
```